# Find domain of $f$ where $f(z)=\ln(z^2-5z+6)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\ln$ is the principal branch of the complex natural logarithm.
I think I've solved it, but I don't know if I covered everything.
Here's what I did:

$Im(z^2-5z+6)>-\pi$ and $Im(z^2-5z+6)\leq\pi$

Then I disassemble the left side as $Im(z^2)-5Im(z)=2Re(z)Im(z)-5Im(z)$.
$$Im(z^2-5z+6)>-\pi$$
$$2Re(z)Im(z)-5Im(z)>-\pi$$
Case $Im(z)>0$:
$$Re(z)>\frac{5Im(z)-\pi}{2Im(z)}$$
and then
$$Im(z^2-5z+6)\leq\pi$$
$$2Re(z)Im(z)-5Im(z)\leq\pi$$
$$Re(z)\leq\frac{5Im(z)+\pi}{2Im(z)}$$
$$Re(z)\in\Big{<}\frac{5Im(z)-\pi}{2Im(z)},\frac{5Im(z)+\pi}{2Im(z)}\Big{]}$$
Case $Im(z)<0$ is analogous:
$$Re(z)\in\Big{[}\frac{5Im(z)+\pi}{2Im(z)},\frac{5Im(z)-\pi}{2Im(z)}\Big{>}$$

So I guess the final domain would be a union of those two cases. Also, for $Im(z)=0$, $Re(z)\in\mathbb R$

Comment: Not sure I am following: the domain of the principal branch of the complex natural logarithm is the set of $z$ in $\mathbb C$ such that $z\ne0$, right? Hence the domain of $f$ is the set of $z$ in $\mathbb C$ such that $z^2-5z+6\ne0$. Thus...

Comment: @Did Oh man. You're right. The image falls in the condition I set, not the domain. So it's just the roots of the polynomial? That sounds a bit too simple.